# WebRTC SurfaceViewRender, how to full screen and not over screen?

Tags: android, webrtc, surfaceview

I use surfaceViewRender to render my remote webRTC stream,
and I want to make the remote stream fill my device screen.
I try this code:

```
pipRenderer.setScalingType(ScalingType.SCALE_ASPECT_FILL);
```

but actually the display size would over my screen size,

[image]

I try to scale the width to fit it:

```
pipRenderer.setScaleX(0.8f);
```

but the result become more strange,

[image]

Does anybody can tell how to do this?

I want make the stream auto fit the screen size but do not over screen,

*I will very appreciate to you!!*

Comment: Found a solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

set `pipRenderer.setScalingType(ScalingType.SCALE_ASPECT_FIT);`  instead of 
`pipRenderer.setScalingType(ScalingType.SCALE_ASPECT_FILL);`  while initializing the renderer

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and response my result!

Comment: but they where never seen again ...